# R (CARET) cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I am trying to train a polynomial support vector machine using the CARET package in R and get the error messages stated in the title of my question. I am having difficulty googling a solution and was wondering if anyone could direct me towards finding a solution.

**My code** is shared below.

```
Train_CTRL <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                           number = 10, repeats = 5)
SVM_Poly <- train(Degree~., 
                  data = Train_Set_Norm, 
                  method = "svmPoly",
                  trControl = Train_CTRL,
                  tuneLength = 1000)
```

**The error:**

> Error in sample.int(n = 1000000L, size = num_rs * nrow(trainInfo$loop) +  :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty simple. It says that in your data set the number of samples is less than 1000. `tuneLength` should be less than the number of samples per group/class present in your dataset. As you have not provided your data, I could able to reproduce your error using `iris` data like

```
library(caret)

Train_CTRL <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                           number = 10, repeats = 5)
SVM_Poly <- train(Species~., 
                  data = iris, 
                  method = "svmPoly",
                  trControl = Train_CTRL,
                  tuneLength = 1000)
```

> Error in sample.int(n = 1000000L, size = num_rs * nrow(trainInfo$loop) +  :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

The `tuneLength = 1000` with 10 fold cross-validation with 5 repeats will generate 1000 x 10 x 5 = 50000 combinations which is computationally intensive. You can use smaller number in `tuneLength` like

```
SVM_Poly <- train(Species~., 
                  data = iris, 
                  method = "svmPoly",
                  trControl = Train_CTRL,
                  tuneLength = 10)
```

Comment: @ Bappa Das Please excuse me for reaching out to you, but I have a similar error using the 'xgbTree' method. I would really appreaciate it, if you could have a look at my question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873150/sampling-error-message-when-applying-carets-train-function

Thank you very much in advance!